# Как описать тип возврата в C#, если он определяется динамически?

Tags: c#

Есть функция.

```
public static DateTime GetAsDateTime(Entity entity);
{
    Field field = entity.GetField(fieldId);
    if (((field != null) ? field.Data : null) != null) {
        Field field2 = entity.GetField(fieldId);
        return (DateTime)((field2 != null) ? field2.Data : null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Она получает сущность и возвращает дату, если она есть или null, если даты нет.

Сейчас получаю ошибку, что DateTime не может быть null.

Что вернуть, если даты нет. Я хочу `null`, но не знаю как это описать на уровне типов.

Comment: Nullable<DateTime> dt; или в короткой нотации DateTime? dt; if(dt.HasValue) { dt.Value; } https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: А это вообще ок ситуация, когда даты нет или не ок? Если не ок, то лучше бросать исключение. Ну а если ок, то либо `nullable`, либо делать функцию `TryGetAsDateTime` c `out` параметром, куда будет класться результат и `boolean` типом метода - успешно всё прошло или нет. Возвращать `null` всё-таки не слишком хорошо.

Comment: `((field != null) ? field.Data : null) != null` бедные мои глаза, прошу перепишите это на `field?.Data != null`